# date print strange in list

Tags: java, date-formatting, date

I have date list

```
  <li class="disabled" id="updDt" style="width: 140px;"></li>


  upd_dt = |2017-06-28 16:27:51.0
```

this updDt is Date. but it print the strange value

 it print as

```
1498634871000
```

Answer (score 0):

`1498634871000` is the equivalent of `2017-06-28 16:27:51.0` in milliseconds.

Check it here: https://www.epochconverter.com/